# Databind a property with passing parameter in a reusable Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, prism

I have a userControl that contains Button and a textbox and i use 3 times in a Page the usercontrol has Codebehind but the rest project is in Mvvm pattern.

In my usercntrol i databind the button click to a property Klick

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty KlickProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( nameof(Klick), typeof(ICommand), typeof(userControl), new PropertyMetadata( default(ICommand) ) );

public ICommand Klick
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue( KlickProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( KlickProperty, value ); }
}
```

On the Usercontrol xaml :

```
<Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding Klick}"/>
```

Now in my PageView i use the 3 controls :

```
<local:userControl Klick="{Binding NavigateToMain}"/>
<local:userControl Klick="{Binding NavigateToMain}"/>
<local:userControl Klick="{Binding NavigateToMain}"/>
```

What i want to do is to be able to pass a string with the Binding so i can know what button was clicked (What user control) something like

**Command="{Binding NavigateToMain}" CommandParameter="Button_from_usercontrol _1"**

Here is the rest of the code

```
class PageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ICommand NavigateToMain{ get; private set; }

    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

public PageViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    _regionManager = regionManager;
   NavigateToMain = new DelegateCommand(() => NavigateTo());
}


    private void NavigateTo()
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(Contentregionn, Main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might well be closed as duplicate... until then, it works the same way as `PROP1` and `PROP2` and `Klick` - create a dependency property and you're good to go.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty KlickParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( nameof(KlickParameter), typeof(object), typeof(userControl), new PropertyMetadata( default(object) ) );

public object KlickParameter
{
    get { return GetValue( KlickParameterProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( KlickParameterProperty, value ); }
}
```